# Window.open retorna NULL u OBJECT en Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

Tengo un sitio web en el cual en un menú creo un `link` con el objetivo de de abrir una pestaña nueva y mantener mi sitio en la pestaña actual, estoy realizando las pruebas en Internet Explorer 8.

Para realizar lo comentado utilizo el siguiente código:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com/', '_blank');">Test</a>
```

**ERROR:**
Cuando doy click en la opción del menú me abre exitosamente la pestaña, sin embargo mi pantalla principal se muestra en blanco y aparece un texto que dice `NULL`.

Leí que desactivando el `Modo Protegido` de internet ya no se mostraría el mensaje de `NULL`, y así fue, solo que ahora me muestra el texto `[OBJECT]`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**NOTA**: Tomar en cuenta que me conecto en una VPN para trabajar (no se si influye en esto).

**SOLUCIÓN DESEADA:**
Abrir una pestaña nueva con la ruta que configuré y conservar mi pantalla principal sin ningún cambio en la pantalla (que no se muestre `NULL` u `OBJECT`).

Espero puedan ayudarme, no comprendo aun a que se debe este inconveniente.

Gracias anticipadas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">link</a>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero, por un momento pensé que tu código era equivalente a lo mío, pero estaba equivocado, gracias por la idea. Saludos :D.